# Java: signed shift performance on long, putting in maps

Tags: java, performance, dictionary, long-integer, bit-shift

I just changed the question a little to get the main focus on shifting.

While I did some shifting, I just recognized that a `<< 32` is incredibly slower than a `<< 16` on long.

So I just created a class for testing shifting and I wonder for the results.
that huge?

Here the full class if you want to try yourself.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int y_start = 0, x_start = 0;
        int y_runs = 1024, x_runs = 1024;
        int y_end = y_start + y_runs, x_end = x_start + x_runs;
        long time = 0;

        System.out.println(y_runs+" * "+x_runs+" = "+(y_runs+1)*(x_runs+1)+" loops each");
        for (int i = 0; i<=64; i++) {
            Map<Long, String> map = new HashMap<Long, String>();
            time = -System.nanoTime();
            for (int y = y_start; y < y_end; y++){
                for (int x = x_start; x < x_end; x++) {
                    map.put(((long) y << i) + (long) x, "ABCDEF");
                }
            }
            time += System.nanoTime();
            System.out.println("<< "+i+": "+time/1000000+"ms");
        }

    }
}
```

I run a test with 512 * 512 loops. Whats interesting that on `<< 29` to `<< 34` it becomes slower than on any other shift, with a peak at `<< 32`.

When I run the same test with 1024 * 1024 loops (equals to +1 Bit or quadrupling) the numbers become incredibly slow. But only from `<< 26` to `<< 37` with the peak at `<< 32` again.

I guess on doubling the loops per dimension will result in a similar increase. So why are the signed shifts around `<< 32` so slow?! That really bugs me.

SOLVED: As pointed out, that the problem is actually the `put()` method of `Map`. Cause it checks for existant entries using the `Long`s `hashCode()`. So the `<< 32` (and close) actually get the worst out of the hashcode results.

Comment: How did you actually test this?

Comment: I just put them in a Map with Integer/Long as Key with simple String like "ABCDEF" as value. I looped 2000*2000 runs to test (incrementing over int). The first takes minutes (~2) and the last seconds (~2). There was no other difference. And autoboxing from long to Long should not takes multiples of int to Integer.

Comment: Please read up on warming up the JVM and proper profiling techniques.  Without having done so, these tests are meaningless.

Comment: I just made the question more precisely to signed shifting problem I face and also the testing. Before voting down, why don't you give a proper explanation? Your answer is contentless... but gave me a downvote? I want to give your downvote a downvote...

Comment: Without some arrangement to take the JITC out of the equation your measurements are meaningless.  You should either disable the JITC or 
"warm up" the code.

Comment: Your are quite contentless as the one before. Performance test by checking the time past with JIT are not meaningless. I never claimed to rely on numbers or their accuracity. It's just to get an indication... However, if you know it better use the code in the environment and settings you suggest and give me the result. See if the behaviour is totally different than I face. Since this code is quite simple, give me your warm up suggestion that makes it that more reliable. Or give me a setting for Eclipse or whatever. But at least give some content. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not measuring shift, but rather `HashMap.put`.
Look at [Long.hashCode()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#hashCode()) implementation and you'll see why `<< 32` is the turning point.

Comment: Hm... I don't know why `<< 32` is the tuning point. Actually `(int)(a ^ (a >>> 32))` with `a` as `long` should result in a very low collision (2 to 3 per hash bucket), doesnt it?

Comment: @chrixle No. The HashMap keys are `((long) y << 32) + (long) x`, where x = 0..1023 and y = 0..1023. There are only 1024 different hash codes for these 1 million values.

Comment: Somehow I was mistaken by the `(a ^ (a >>> half-of-bit-length)` thing. I looked up the hashcode to verify it's not the hashcode of Long and though it's some issue of how those operators may be implemented - the `<< 32` misleads me to 32/64 bit architecture. On a second thought it's somewhat clear, lol... Guess I was tired. However, thanks for pointing out and actually looking the spot I pointed out to have a problem - and not saying something like "your problem is irrelevant because of some nonsense". :) PS: Adjusted the question a little and the tags to point the issue.